# Are the functions $|x|-1$, $(x^2-1)^4$, and $(x^4-1)^2$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Determine if functions $$|x|-1,\quad (x^2-1)^4,\quad (x^4-1)^2$$ are linearly independent.

I want to do this without using the Wronskian. Do I need to make the equation
$$\lambda_1(|x|-1)+\lambda_2(x^2-1)^4+\lambda_3(x^4-1)^2=0$$
and analyse this by plugging in different values for $x$ and seeing what I get? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No better way. Just plug in some values of $x$ and show that all the coefficients are $0$.

Comment: Yep, plugging in numbers is a perfectly sensible way to approach this. There are ad-hoc methods too. You could, for example, observe that $|x| - 1$ is not a polynomial (proof: if it were, then $|x| - x = |x| - 1 - (x - 1)$ would be a polynomial, non-zero, with infinitely many roots), so it can't possibly be in the span of the other two. Then you just need to show that the other functions are not scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @TheoBendit $|x|-x=|x|-1-(x-1)$ is what you want for that argument.

Comment: @J.G. Indeed. Thank you! I edited my comment.

Comment: $|x|$ is not differentiable, and cannot be a polynomial, and the two polynomials are distinct.

Comment: @PatBol A better proof that $|x| - 1$ is not a polynomial, but distinctness is not enough. For example, $x$ and $2x$ are distinct as well.

Comment: @TheoBendit: quite right. I should have said linearly independent coefficients. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x=0,1,\sqrt2$ and ponder dependence of the vectors $(-1,1,1), (-1,0,0)$ and $(\sqrt2-1,1,9)$.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices to consider $x>0$ for which we have
$$\lambda_1(x-1) + \lambda_2(x^2-1)^4 + \lambda_3(x^4-1)^2 = 0.$$
If the coefficients were not $0$, then this polynomial can have at most $8$ roots, but since it has infinitely many roots, we can conclude that all the coefficients of the polynomial must be $0$. In particular the coefficient for $x$, which is $\lambda_1$, the coefficient for $x^2$, which is $\lambda_2 {4 \choose 1} (-1)^3$, and the coefficient for $x^8$, which is $\lambda_2 + \lambda_3,$ must all be $0$. Clearly this implies $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.